# How type tabular data with metadata in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

We have the following format from out backend, which has `data` part that is just tabular data and a `meta` part that describes the columns in the table. The metadata holds the information about the type for each column.

**Example**

```
{
 meta: [
  {name: "foo", type: "NUMBER"},
  {name: "bar", type: "STRING"},
  {name: "baz", type: "TIMESTAMP"},
 ],
  data:[
    [1, "a", 12121232],
    [2, "b", 12121232],
    [3, "c", 12121232],
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to type the relation between `meta` and `data` in TypeScript?

The goal is to have this function to be typechecked successfully, so i can use the type info from the `meta` info instead of checking the content of every table cell:

```
const fn = (data:Data) => {
  if(data.meta[1].type ==='STRING'){
    data.data[0][1].concat('-bar')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). As we know that `data[0][0]` is a string when `meta[0].type` is a string, we can tell Typescript it should just assume that it is a string. So [adapted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwCrmgXigcgHICqAsgEICiASjlAD64DKqFAkngOLV06rNFmMBBIgAUcAbgCwAKGkB6WVHoBXMGABOEAM6aoAdwCGagHZwjAcyhmIRiGv3AIyKACMQUJUaWbHUUJChghvoAthAOalAABvSRcgpaiKbAALTIcJr6zogQyTYAHimJNlAAAn5aAMZqcGApCUmyRgD2yR5ejskAboaa0km2AGb6FdDokMjwSMgAPKhQEAXWyDqTKGMQADSKAHxQAN7SUFBGIRAAXFCawNXmklJH5ReodwC%200tLlUHhKwc62q05sOsJggUNN8MRyFQtp5frZtndPvRrqYzACoECMCCpuDGCx2DgtlcbmYER8MFBUHBQlcQmB0ZjxgDwTw%20IIRITjj8-moyTIpJ8GV9uf9QU46MiSei6FSacA6QC7uT-OsmgNmTBdtgYPNFkZlpSsczTANbJStiazfRdgB%20Q1MsWzLbW3UOfUrMVQO30KAXGydM1%20iABtRKqT9NRDEZQAAi9n0%200OUFC8ouAjUdhA0wBfKOyHjaYz%20izeygAG0ANJQUxQMgFOwVYDTADWEBAat8AAt0mWcCn9DgALowkW8wdPDBq5nAbuaXv9oeVwcIqAvPlvfkVJpGK5QfOp2PxjGJ%207JsL6C5lpNHUsnUIXABEAyaTQfW0eUAfhFIlAfq42177McpyPs4hhvr4GCPnirBsH%20LwAaeN7Afen5gQAXhBH4Pqy-CoEIwjwYhRzDkm%204XleSHllAACMWwPvoEE0QATCxLEAMzMVApFUWWUDMfRzhMaxImcdxxFHNR7H0RUwlscxYk8SRiEvGGW47sAUADEYx4ABTkWccbygAlBiuwHKecADPp8YAHT9mWNGDrZnyYG5OAwQSxkWZJUA2fKtnkWWAAMg6OYOUD6DokqosZtnqRU9i6TgyRgWoODGUmG4vEAA) @MTCoters answer using `as` to make it work:

```
type FieldType = 'NUMBER' | 'STRING' | 'TIMESTAMP';

// Suppress warning generated by unused type parameter `S`
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
interface TypedField<T extends FieldType, S> {
  name: string;
  type: T;
}

type NumberField = TypedField<'NUMBER', number>;
type StringField = TypedField<'STRING', string>;
type TimestampField = TypedField<'TIMESTAMP', number>;

type Field = NumberField | StringField | TimestampField;

type TypeofField<F> = F extends TypedField<infer T, infer S> ? TypedField<T, S> extends Field ? S : never : never;

interface Data {
  meta: Array<Field>;
  data: Array<{ [K in Extract<keyof this['meta'], number>]: TypeofField<this['meta'][K]>; }>;
}

const data: Data = {
  meta: [
    { name: "foo", type: "NUMBER" },
    { name: "bar", type: "STRING" },
    { name: "baz", type: "TIMESTAMP" },
  ],
  data:[
    [ 1, "a", 12121232 ],
    [ 2, "b", 12121232 ],
    [ 3, "c", 12121232 ],
  ],
};

const fn = (data:Data) => {
  if(data.meta[1].type ==='STRING'){
    (data.data[0][1] as String).concat('-bar')
  }
}
```

Note that it would fail when removing `as String`.

Answer (score 1):

I actually typed up something similar recently. Inspired by that, here's what I came up with for your situation ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwCrmgXigcgHICqAsgEICiASjlAD64DKqFAkngOLV06rNFmMBBIgAUcAbgCwAKGkB6WVHoBXMGABOEAM6aoAdwCGagHZwjAcyhmIRiGv3AIyKACMQUJUaWbHUUJChghvoAthAOalAABvSRcgpaiKbAALTIcJr6zogQyTYAHimJNlAAAn5aAMZqcGApCUmyRgD2yR5ejskAboaa0km2AGb6FdDokMjwSMgAPKhQEAXWyDqTKGMQADSKAHxQAN7SUFBGIRAAXFCawNXmklJH5ReodwC+0tLlUHhKwc62q05sOsJggUNN8MRyFQtp5frZtndPvRrqYzACoECMCCpuDGCx2DgtlcbmYER8MFBUHBQlcQmB0ZjxgDwTw+IIRITjj8-moyTIpJ8GV9uf9QU46MiSei6FSacA6QC7uT-OsmgNmTBdtgYPNFkZlpSsczTANbJStiazfRdgB+Q1MsWzLbW3UOfUrMVQO30KAXGydM1+iABtRKqT9NRDEZQAAi9n0+0OUFC8ouAjUdhA0wBfKOyHjaYz+izeygAG0ANJQUxQMgFOwVYDTADWEBAat8AAt0mWcCn9DgALowkW8wdPDBq5nAbuaXv9oeVwcIqAvPlvfkVJpGK5QfOp2PxjGJ+7JsL6C5lpNHUsnUIXABEAyaTQfW0eUAfhFIlAfq42177McpyPs4hhvr4GCPnirBsH+LwAaeN7Afen5gQAXhBH4Pqy-CoEIwjwYhRzDkm+4XleSHllAACMWwPvoEE0QATCxLEAMzMVApFUWWUDMfRzhMaxImcdxxFHNR7H0RUwlscxYk8SRiEvHcQA)):

```js
type FieldType = 'NUMBER' | 'STRING' | 'TIMESTAMP';

// Suppress warning generated by unused type parameter `S`
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
interface TypedField<T extends FieldType, S> {
  name: string;
  type: T;
}

type NumberField = TypedField<'NUMBER', number>;
type StringField = TypedField<'STRING', string>;
type TimestampField = TypedField<'TIMESTAMP', number>;

type Field = NumberField | StringField | TimestampField;

type TypeofField<F> = F extends TypedField<infer T, infer S> ? TypedField<T, S> extends Field ? S : never : never;

interface Data {
  meta: Array<Field>;
  data: Array<{ [K in Extract<keyof this['meta'], number>]: TypeofField<this['meta'][K]>; }>;
}

const data: Data = {
  meta: [
    { name: "foo", type: "NUMBER" },
    { name: "bar", type: "STRING" },
    { name: "baz", type: "TIMESTAMP" },
  ],
  data: [
    [ 1, "a", 12121232 ],
    [ 2, "b", 12121232 ],
    [ 3, "c", 12121232 ],
  ],
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this will not solve. my problem. I've updated my question as it's seems a bit unclear what I'm after.